# How to reference Controller / Bootstrap node in a bundle

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I am using the standard juju charm bundle for openstack on 4 machines (slightly modified). I would like the bootstrap node to be machine 0 of those 4 machines however when I specify machines in the bundle 0 through 3, it creates 4 NEW machines in the deployment.  So I end up with a total of 5 machines.

This is a dense MAAS Openstack deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Use juju quickstart to deploy the bundle and use the format shown in the code block below in your bundle.yaml.

```
machines:
  '0':
    constraints: tags=bootstrap
    series: trusty
  '1':
    constraints: tags=anytag
    series: trusty
  '2':
    constraints: tags=anytag
    series: trusty
  '3':
    constraints: tags=anytag
    series: trusty
relations:
- - mysql
  - keystone
- - keystone
  - glance
- - cinder
  - mysql
- - glance
  - cinder
series: trusty
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:trusty/percona-cluster
    num_units: 1
    options:
      max-connections: 20000
      source: cloud:trusty-mitaka
    to:
    - '0'
  keystone:
    charm: cs:trusty/keystone
    num_units: 1
    options:
      admin-password: plumgrid
      admin-token: ubuntutesting
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-mitaka
    to:
    - '1'
  cinder:
    charm: cs:trusty/cinder
    num_units: 1
    options:
      block-device: None
      glance-api-version: 2
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-mitaka
      overwrite: 'true'
      remove-missing-force: true
    to:
    - '2'
  glance:
    charm: cs:trusty/glance
    num_units: 1
    options:
      debug: true
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-mitaka
      verbose: true
    to:
    - '3'
```

See also:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-bundles#machine-specifications-and-bundle-placement-directives

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy and select which machine will be your controller.

Just add a tag to the machine that you want to be the controller and then specify it in the juju command with a constraint (`--constraints`).

```
juju bootstrap --constraints tags=juju mymaas maas-controller
```

For more info check [this OpenStack link](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/stein/install-openstack.html).